# organizing songs by artist | python, eyed3

Tags: python, directory

i'm trying to write code to organize +40Gs of music, i want to organize by artist, so far i've been able to get the artist info, but i'm working on creating a directory for each artist and having songs with the same artist go into the same directory instead of creating an individual directory for each song.

```
import os #imports os functions
import eyed3 #imports eyed3 functions

root_folder = '/Users/ntoscano/desktop/mp3-organizer'

files = os.listdir(root_folder) #lists all files in specified directory
if not files[1].endswith('.mp3'):
    pass #if the file does not end with ".mp3" it does not load it into eyed3

for file_name in files:
    #if file_name.endswith('.mp3'): continue #if file ends with ".mp3" it continues onto the next line

    abs_location = '%s/%s' % (root_folder, file_name)

    song_info = eyed3.load(abs_location) #loads each file into eyed3 and assignes the return value to song_info
    if song_info is None:
        print 'Skippig %s' % abs_location
        continue
     os.mkdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/mp3-organizer/%s')) % song_info.tag.artist
     print song_info
     print song_info.tag.artist
```

this is what i have so far, but it's broken, line 19 always gives me an error,

```
Nicolass-MacBook-Air:mp3-organizer ntoscano$ python eyeD3test.py 
Skippig /Users/ntoscano/desktop/mp3-organizer/.DS_Store
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eyeD3test.py", line 19, in <module>
    os.mkdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/mp3-organizer/%s')) % song_info.tag.artist
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'unicode'
```

i'm new to coding, so i'm sure it's a simple error, but i just don't understand how i can get a directory made with the artist info as the name. any help is apreciated

Comment: I'm just doing a similar work. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131461/python-fix-a-broken-encoding) i scan for files with [beets](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/beets/1.0rc2) library, may be it will be useful for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is just parentheses in the wrong place. Instead of this:

```
os.mkdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/mp3-organizer/%s')) % song_info.tag.artist
```

Do this:

```
os.mkdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/mp3-organizer/%s' % song_info.tag.artist))
```

This is easier to see if you break it down into pieces:

```
expanded = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/mp3-organizer/%s')
dir = os.mkdir(expanded)
formatted = dir % song_info.tag.artist
```

So, you're making a directory called `/Users/ntoscano/Desktop/mp3-organizer/%s`, and that's returning `None`, and then you're doing `None % song_info.tag.artist`, hence the error about  `NoneType` and `unicode` being unsupported for `%`.

It doesn't matter in this case whether you do the formatting before or after the `expanduser`, but you have to do it before the `mkdir`.

As a side note, even though it's legal, it's generally a bad idea to use a single value instead of a tuple for `%`-formatting (`'~/Desktop/mp3-organizer/%s' % (song_info.tag.artist,)'`). And it's generally an even better idea to use modern `{}` formatting instead (`'~/Desktop/mp3-organizer/{}'.format(song_info.tag.artist)`). And it's even better to use `os.path` instead of string manipulation, so none of these problems even come up in the first place.

Also, I notice you're using a hand-expanded `root_folder` in some cases, but `expanduser` in others. You probably want to be consistent about this—otherwise, it'll break as soon as you try to use it on another machine where `~` isn't `/Users/ntoscano`. And, even though OS X allows you to get pathname cases wrong in some cases, you should get them right whenever possible.

Putting it all together:

```
root_folder = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/mp3-organizer')

files = os.listdir(root_folder) #lists all files in specified directory

for file_name in files:
    #if file_name.endswith('.mp3'): continue #if file ends with ".mp3" it continues onto the next line

    abs_location = os.path.join(root_folder, file_name)

    song_info = eyed3.load(abs_location) #loads each file into eyed3 and assignes the return value to song_info
    if song_info is None:
        print 'Skippig %s' % abs_location
        continue
     os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_folder, song_info.tag.artist))
     print song_info
     print song_info.tag.artist
```